# JQuery Mobile Form submission returns to Homepage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've built a Jquery Mobile Android App using Phonegap which contains a form with an on submit action which triggers the following script -

```
function searchThis() {

var inputDetails= $('.srchInput').val();

$('.srchRes').empty();
$('.srchRes').append('<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300"    frameborder="0"   src="http://uc.dialogue.net/srch.jsp?query='+inputDetails+'&searchMode=any&indexGroup=Default"></iframe>');

return false;

}
```

The function of the form works great - my problem is that when the form submit the app navigates to the homepage?   I cant figure out why this is happening or how to stop it!?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth trying to use event.preventDefault(); as well as returning false, see if that helps.